# Has anyone studied lattices of graphs organized by inclusion?

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

Suppose we have two directed graphs, A and B, each represented as a set of ordered pairs (x,y) of natural numbers, such that x and y represent vertices and (x,y) represents a directed edge from x to y.

Let's define A ⊆ B to be true iff there exists an injective function F: A → B such that if two pairs in A share the same first, resp. second element, then their images also share the same first, resp. second element. That is, one could take the graph A and overlay it atop B and it would match some part of B.

A variant of this subset relation might be more strict in requiring that the images of A's vertices under F do not have any edges between them that are not images of edges in A. By the former relation, a graph of three vertices in the shape a->b->c would be a subset of a triangle with all edges bidirectional - but not by the latter.

Either way, one could construct a lattice of graphs this way, with each point in the lattice corresponding to a graph, and given L(X) takes graph X to its corresponding lattice point, then A ⊆ B would imply that L(A) ≤ L(B). Meet and join could then be defined as well, though I do not know if they are guaranteed to be unique - I suspect not.

So, my question is basically, has this been done? Does anyone study lattices of graphs ordered under one of these types of inclusion, or some other I haven't thought of? Is there even anything interesting TO study there? If so, I'd love to see some references to papers or books about this subject.

Comment: Your definition of graph does not include isolated vertices and leaves the puzzle if there are one or two directed loops from v to v.

Comment: Maybe you could improve the formulation of your question by asking "if the set of graphs defined on a given set of nodes form a lattice". I find a bit unclear what you're asking, and I'm not sure my suggestion would actually be what you have in mind. I should think the answer to this question, should be yes, provided all these graphs have loops in every node (and then the meet would just be the intersection of edges, giving a complete lattice, having as a bottom the graph with only the loops and as a top the complete graph).